# Cannot convert localized moment.js string to unix time, or any format

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs

I am trying to convert a localized datetime string to unix time in moment.js, but to no avail.  Does anyone know a workaround to do this?

```
moment.locale('de');
var a = moment('20.06.2015').format("X"); //returns Invalid Date
var b = moment('20.06.2015').unix(); //returns Invalid Date
```

Comment: Or, is there a way to convert the localized time to the English time?

Comment: Your input format is making Moment unhappy. If you change the "." to "/" then it works fine. Maybe the default format for the "de" locale does not involve "."

Comment: When I do var z = moment().format("L"); I get 03.08.2015 for z...the format is right, I suppose the method seems to support only the english date....unless I am missing something?

Comment: Try `moment('20.06.2015', 'DD.MM.YYYY').format("X");` for example

Comment: I think the "locale" stuff is mostly about output formatting, but I'm not a Monent.js expert.

Comment: @Pointy That did the trick!  Thank you!  Do you know if there is a way to get the format string (in this case 'DD.MM.YYYY') from a localized moment()?

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't, sorry. Perhaps there's something you can do to extend the Moment locale extension so that it does it automatically. Again, I've only used Moment a little bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Always* supply a format when you parse.

```
moment.locale('de');
var a = moment('20.06.2015', 'DD.MM.YYYY').unix();
```

If you want, you can use the locale-defined formats.  For German, the `L` format is `DD.MM.YYYY`.

```
moment.locale('de');
var a = moment('20.06.2015', 'L').unix();
```

This is useful if you might change locales and want the format to change to match.

Comment: Fantastic!  Thank you!!